# Copy rows into a Workbook sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, copy-paste

Am very new and have been trying my best to self help myself but after a hour or so I have give up and now need help, I am trying to use the below code I have found on here to  copy the "OK" lines in Workbook 1 sheet 1 column I into a new sheet in workbook 2 sheet 1.

I don't need to copy the "ERROR" part but have left this in until I got the code working.

I would also like to keep all the data copied in to workbook 2 as at the moment the previous date is being replaced with the new data.

```
    FilterAndCopy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim OKSheet As Worksheet, ErrorSheet As Worksheet

Set OKSheet = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Set This to the Sheet name you want all Ok's going to
Set ErrorSheet = Sheets("Sheet2") ' Set this to the Sheet name you want all Error's going to

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


With Range("A1", "I" & lngLastRow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="OK"
    .Copy OKSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="ERROR"
    .Copy ErrorSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is not working because you need to write

```
 sub FilterAndCopy()
```

At the beggining of your sub, try it and see if it works.

What you can do to check if there is data in the colum is:

```
Dim r as range
set r = Range("a1")
 while r.value <> ""
  r= r.offset(0,1)
 end while
```

and use "r" as your paste range instead of A1

Comment: sorry missing that off, how would I stop it from replacing the data every time I copy it over to the new sheet?

Comment: It depends, if you want to keep the data in the book you can either check if there is something in the column and paste it in the next one or change the paste-range in the code every time you run the macro. (option 1 is more suitable)

Comment: how would I change the above code to check if there is something in the column and paste it thanks for your help

Comment: First of all, have you run the code already? it is pasting the data in another workbook? because I don't see it, so the code below is not suitable for your task.

Comment: no up to now it is only pasting the data in to another sheet within the same workbook was trying to work on one thing at a time any help with either would be good